# Why isn't the selectedIndex property returning the option that is selected?

Tags: jquery, html-select

I'm using JQuery 1.12.  I'm having trouble using JQuery to get the selected index of a menu item.  I have this HTML:

```
<select class="selectField selectMenu form-control" name="user[address_attributes][state_id]" id="user_address_attributes_state_id"><option value="">Select State</option>
    <option value="3526">Alabama</option>
    <option value="3556">Alaska</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="3547">Arizona</option>
    <option value="3510">Arkansas</option>
    <option value="3542">California</option>
    <option value="3543">Colorado</option>
    <!-- rest omitted for brevity -->
</select>
```

You can see that the "selected" is populated next to the "Arizona" option.  However, when I try and use JQuery to find the seleted index, it just returns zero ...

```
$('#user_address_attributes_state_id')[0].selectedIndex
0
```

However, when I select the option by its value, I do see taht it is selected ...

```
$('#user_address_attributes_state_id option[value="3547"]').attr("selected")
"selected"
```

You can see that nothing else is selected in my HTML.  How do I use jQuery to accurately return the selected index of my menu?

Comment: Are you running `$('#user_address_attributes_state_id')[0].selectedIndex` from the console or from the page? It works for me when run in page.

Comment: @cale_b the `[0]` dereferences the jQuery object and returns the underlying DOM node. See https://api.jquery.com/get/ "Each jQuery object also masquerades as an array, so we can use the array dereferencing operator to get at the list item instead:"

Comment: @j08691 - cool, thanks for the info! I am always learning something new on SO!

Comment: In an effort to debug things, all the output I have is coming from my console.  Since I'm using the complete ID, does it matter whether I'm running from the console or inside a JS file that's included on my page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the selected option:

```
var selected_option =  $('#user_address_attributes_state_id option:selected');
```

and selected index:

```
 var selected_index = $('#user_address_attributes_state_id option:selected').index();
```

and select option by `value="3547"`:

```
 $('#user_address_attributes_state_id').val(3547);
```

Comment: Excellent and thorough. Nice answer.

Comment: Never thought about the third option, nice.

Comment: As I'm looking for the selected index, I tried your second option, "$('#user_address_attributes_state_id option:selected').index()", but it is returning zero given the above HTML.  Note that when I run "$('#user_address_attributes_state_id').html()" it returns '<option value="">Select State</option>
<option value="3526">Alabama</option>
<option value="3556">Alaska</option>
<option value="3547" selected="selected">Arizona</option>
<option value="3510">Arkansas</option>...'